# About using indexes in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

Question is about when to use or not indexes. If I have a table with 10 billions of rows and have status a column on each row. I want to search rows depending on status, so I want to define an Index on this column. We have around 5 different statuses with majority of records are on 2 / 3 of them. However, when I read this article
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html#useWhenIndex__when-no-index , it seems that each status type will be a row. So my questions:

1- is this index will be able to refer to all these number of rows?

2- can we define an index on multi column?

3- if a status is updated using spark job, this job should not update more than 100k cells ? Means 100k rows statuses ( [LINK](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html#useWhenIndex__when-no-index) )

4- is it better to use a view for each status?